# Monitor Mode doesn't work in Kali 2.0

Tags: linux, wireshark, kali-linux

For the last year or so I have been using this exact setup with Kali 1.0. Everything worked fine with Wireshark. Now, when I am connected to a Wi-Fi access point my card REFUSES to stay in monitor mode. I have tried the following.

Scenario 1:

1. Live boot Kali 2.0
2. Open terminal
3. $airmon-ng start wlan1 (a USB wireless adapter I have used for sniffing in the past)
4. output is now wlan1mon (I understand why it outputs this I read the Kali docs)
5. Connect to my home network
6. Open Wireshark and listen to wlan1mon
7. I only see Broadcast ARP requests and traffic from my machine

Scenario 2:

1. Live boot Kali 2.0
2. Open terminal
3. ifconfig wlan1 down
4. iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
5. ifconfig wlan1 up
6. Connect to my home network
7. Open wireshark and listen to wlan1
8. I only see Broadcast ARP requests and traffic from my machine

I'm not sure what it's problem is.

Answer (score 0):

after starting monitor the system it will suggest some process that may cause troubles...try killing them...and using monitor and connecting to a network may cause troubles...

Comment: There are no processes conflicting. Using monitor mode while connected to a network is the only way to see packets from other machines...

Comment: did u search if ur the only one having this problem?

Comment: Ehhh yeah... Kali 2.0 released this month... Not a ton of documentation on fringe cases just yet... All I know is that I have been using the same tools AND process on Kali 1.0 and all was fine...

Comment: could be the programmers fault?

Answer (score 0):

In scenario 1, after 4th point:
try these:

```
ifconfig wlan1mon down
iwconfig wlan1mon0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan1mon up
```

Then to test and sniff the network:

```
airodump-ng wlan1mon
```

Comment: I will attempt this the next time I have that system booted. Have you tried this yet? It seems suspect that it would work. wlan1mon is the name of the interface not wlan1mon0. I think this will result in a interface not found error.